# Convert Integer to Hex where decimal 1 representation is FFFFFF

Tags: java, algorithm, integer, hex

I have been trying to solve the following mock exam paper problem, unfortunately, I am unable to rationalise how it is possible to transform the decimal 1 into hexadecimal "ffffff" string. Hopefully, someone could point me in the right direction, since even the actual Integer.toHextString returns 1 hexadecimal string for 1 decimal.

Problem statement:

> Suppose that you are forbidden from using printf or
> Integer.toHexString, or indeed any other existing library way of doing
> it, but you still need to display a Java integer in hexadecimal as one
> to eight digits. For instance, you are to display the number 19
> (decimal) as the string 13, and 1 must come out as ffffffff.
>
> Write a Java method called toHex that takes an integer as its argument
> and returns the string form of the hexadecimal representation of that
> number

My code is as follows:

```java
public class Main {
    public static String toHex(int d) {
        String digits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
        if (d <= 0) return "0";
        int base = 16; 
        String hex = "";
        while (d > 0) {
            int digit = d % base;              // rightmost digit
            hex = digits.charAt(digit) + hex;  // string concatenation
            d = d / base;
        }
        return hex;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(-1)); // outputs: ffffff
        System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(1)); // outputs: 1
        System.out.println(Main.toHex(1)); // outputs: 1
    }
}
```

Comment: There must be a typo in the problem description; 'the number 1 comes out at ffffffff' just does not make sense. For example, if it said `-1 must come out as ffffffff`, that makes perfect sense (look up "two's complement"). To fix you code to work properly with negative numbers, you probably want to look into `>>` and `&` (the bitwise operators), and forget about the notion of bases.

Comment: Indeed a typo, probably caused by a copy/paste issue. I found [this source](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/exams/pastpapers/y2006p1q3.pdf)

Comment: @rzwitserloot, thank you, I will take a look at it now and work out a solution.

Comment: @trincot, nice finding, most probably my lecturer made a mistake during copy/pasting, thanks for that, now I can work out a solution since the confusion is cleared up!

Comment: A more complete copy (with context) can be found on [maths.cam.ac.uk](https://www.maths.cam.ac.uk/undergrad/pastpapers/files/2006/PaperIA_5.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem as follows:

```java
public class Main {
    public static String toHex(int d) {
        if(d == 0) {
            return "0";
        }

        String codes = "0123456789abcdef";

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(8);
        builder.setLength(8);

        for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
            /**
             * 19 in binary is 10011 and 15 is 01111, when using & (and) bitwise operator
             * It becomes 00011, which is 3
             */
            builder.setCharAt(i, codes.charAt(d & 15));
            /**
             *  Right arithmetic shift, for example:
             *  19 in binary is 10011 after shifting to the right 4 places it becomes
             *  00001
             */
            d >>= 4;
        }

        return removeLeadingZeros(builder.toString());
    }

    public static String removeLeadingZeros(String str){
        StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder(str);
        int index = 0;

        while (strB.length() > 0 && strB.charAt(index) == '0') {
            strB.deleteCharAt(index);
        }

        return strB.toString();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(toHex(-1).equals(Integer.toHexString(-1))); // true
        System.out.println(toHex(19).equals(Integer.toHexString(19))); // true
    }
}
```

I want to say thanks to [@rzwitserloot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/768644/rzwitserloot) and [@trincot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5459839/trincot) for pointing me in the right direction.

The hex code can be found at [eddmann](https://eddmann.com/posts/decimal-to-hexadecimal-using-bitwise-bit-shift-operations-in-java/), I added some comments and the ability to remove leading zeroes.

Hopefully, this helps others with a similar types of questions.

More about [Arithmetic Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift) and [Bitwise Operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)